# How to fetch gif from Fresco SimpleDraweeView?

Tags: android, fresco

I'm using Fresco to show gif, I want to save the same gif on sd card. As gif must already be in memory, is there any way to get that gif from memory to sd card instead of downloading again from server.

I have already tried to get it [directly from pipeline](https://guides.codepath.com/android/displaying-images-with-the-fresco-library) but no luck in case of gif, it's working only with images.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try using `imagePipeline.fetchEncodedImage` in ImagePipeline?
`FetchDecodedImage` will not work for gifs but `fetchEncodedImage` should give you the raw image from disk cache.